# How to make a slide menu bar without storyboards and cocoa pods

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I am trying to make a left slide menu bar programmatically with no external plugins, but I can't seem to find any good tutorials on how to achieve this.

The slide menu will only be available on one view controller - which is the initial view controller.

I was hoping to make something like KYDrawerController.
https://github.com/ykyouhei/KYDrawerController

The only reason I am put off using any cocoapods is that I am concerned about it will take a while for an update when the new versions of swift are released.

Does anyone know any good tutorials to make something like this or is it worth just using KYDrawerController?

Comment: Is this a drawer that will always be available with a pan gesture no matter what view controller is in view (like Twitter's UI) or is this a drawer that is only available from one view controller?

Comment: It will only be visible in one view controller. I’m guessing that makes it easier?

Comment: Just take a standard `UIView` and, using constraints, make it the height of the view controller's view with its trailing anchor anchored to the view's leading anchor. Then add a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` on the view controller's view whose translation updates the constraint of the drawer view. That's basically it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a bunch of tutorials and examples to consider studying. (With a little more searching, I'm sure you can easily quadruple this list.) Pick yer poison. :)

[Making a Hamburger (slide-out) Menu in Swift 3](https://medium.com/yay-its-erica/making-a-hamburger-slide-out-menu-in-swift-3-ef5249b6693e)

[How to Create Your Own Slide-Out Navigation Panel in Swift](https://www.raywenderlich.com/78568/create-slide-out-navigation-panel-swift)

[Left side menu (Navigation Drawer) example with Swift](http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/left-side-menu-navigation-drawer-example-with-swift/)

[Left Side Navigation menu or Navigation Drawer example in Swift with MMDrawerController](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c-Uwa5v_3sc)

[How To Add a Slide-out Sidebar Menu in Your Apps](https://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/)

[MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController)

At the heart of implementing the infamous "hamburger" menu (left side nav menu) is to set up a view with constraints that you set up some IBOutlets for in the view controller.  Then when the hamburger button is tapped, manipulate the constants of those constraints to cause the view to slide to right or left, to make room for the left menu or to hide the left menu.

The right view could be a container view that the rest of your app's view controllers live within, for example. See the tutorials for detailed examples, but that's the idea of it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19126266)

Comment: Ok, sure, see edit.